# How to compute $\pi$ with optimal convergence using a Taylor Polynomial of fixed order? Which $f(x)$ to use and at which point $x_0$?

Tags: calculus

How to compute $\pi$ with optimal convergence using a Taylor Polynomial of fixed order?
Which $f(x)$ to use and at which point $x_0$?

By "optimal convergence" I mean the smallest possible error for a given order of the polynomial.

I am aware there are other methods which are more efficient, but my question is specific related to Taylor Polynomials.

I know that one way of doing is:

$\arctan x = \displaystyle x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7}$

for $x=1$ resulting in

$\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{4} = 1 - \displaystyle \frac13 + \frac15 - \frac17 + ... $

However, I do not want to use integrals and I do not know if the series below provides optimal convergence.

Source: https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30001.1-3.shtml

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about what you consider to be an "allowed" formula for $\pi$. You can get silly things otherwise, for example expanding the function $f(x) = x$ about $\pi$ gives $\pi + (x - \pi)$ as the series, which converges very fast but is probably not helpful.

Comment: See [List_of_formulae_involving_π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80)

Comment: I understand your concern. In fact, to expand $f(x)=x$ at $x_0 = \pi$ it is definitely not helpful for computation purposes. So, my question is about a useful formula for computing $\pi$ using only simple operations like sums or subtractions, multiplications, divisions and powers.

Comment: For example, for the equation above $\displaystyle \pi = 4 \left(1 - \displaystyle \frac13 + \frac15 - \frac17 + ...\right)$.

Is there any other expansion that converges faster? Other than that, I am also interested in having an equation for computing $\pi$ without using integrals in its deduction.

In the list of formulae of the link above I could find any formula for computing $\pi$ using Taylor polynomials.

Comment: There are many other formulae which converge faster. Is there any reason you're interested in Taylor series specifically? Taylor series approximate a function in a region, which is something different to what you seem to be trying to do, which is just to approximate a number.

Comment: Do this formulae are based on Taylor series?
I am interested in Taylor series speciifically just as a curiosity.
For example, one can compute the Euler number $e$ with 4 digits of precision using a Taylor series. It is straithfoward to calcule which should be the order of the Taylor polynomial that satisfies the requested precision. By Taylor series, one can also compute $\sqrt{9.03}$ without using a calculator with the "sqrt" function. This is what I found interesting.

Comment: Is there any similar way to do so for $\pi$? If so, which is the polynomial that allows the smallest order for a given fixed precision?
As I said I would like to avoid the formula above because it requires integration.

Comment: I am sorry for too many comments, but I forgot to say that in the case of computing $\pi$, one can use $f(x)=e^x$ and $x_0=0$.